# Symfony2 add specificc assets on dev

Tags: symfony, assets, assetic

Is there a way to add an assets only if it's a dev environment:
I would like to add Holder.js on my layout, but only if it's dev mod, as it shouldn't be added in production.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious way is to check the Twig variable `{% if app.environment == 'dev' %}{% endif %}` and put a script tag inside.

Not the cleanest way, but it does work.

Comment: Generally should avoid environment conditions, and apply configuration by environment instead. I don't see harm in this case if it's dev only though.